# Oracle constraint to check if salary for Director is >5000

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

This is a very beginner question, but my google skills have failed me and I can't seem to find anything relevant in my notes.

I have this situation :
Database **bdamr** with table **functie_amr** and column **denumire_functie**(varchar2) 
Database **bdeur** with table **functie_eur** and columns **sal_min**(number(5)), **sal_max**(number(5)). 
I need to check that the denumire_funtie with value 'Director' has sal_min < 5000 .
The tables were result of vertical fragmentation.

In other words can a constraint compare values in a different table, and  the other table can be in a different database ?

Amongst other I've tried this

```
 alter table functie_eur
   add constraint sal_min_dir 
   check (functie_amr@bdamr.denumire_funtie='Director' and salariu_minim>5000);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at this article http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php
It says you cant compare values from two different table.

Comment: Thanks, Asfakul Islam. 
I guess the only alternative is to do the check with a insert or update trigger !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link [CHECK CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)

You cannot compare values from other table using check constraint, whether the table is  in
same database or other database.

From oracle document:

*The condition of a check constraint can refer to any column in the table, but it cannot refer to columns of other tables.*

If you want to restrict column values insertion you can write [triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm) for that table